# Format specifier for a pointer to a structure

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Graph
{
     int v;
};

int main()
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph -> v = 1;
    printf("%u", graph);
    return 0;
}
```

But I get a warning regarding the format in line:

```
printf("%u", graph);
```

The warning is:

> /home/praveen/Dropbox/algo/c_codes/r_2e/main.c|14|warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct Graph *’ [-Wformat=]|

What format specifier should I use for type `struct Graph *`?

Comment: What does the documentation say is the correc format specifier?

Comment: There's no format specifier for type `struct Graph *`. The question makes no sense whatsoever until you specify what it is you want to print. The address stored in the pointer? Or something else?

Comment: http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: `printf("%u", graph);` --> `printf("%p", (void *)graph);`

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: What you *could* do to print `struct Graph`'s member `V` is: `printf("%d\n", *((int*) graph));` (using `%u` is wrong as it expects an `unsigned int`). Please note, that this only works as `V` is the **first** member of `struct Graph`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard only specifies format specifiers for pre-defined types. The extended MACROs are there to print the fixed-width integers but there exist no format specifier for *whole* user-defined / aggregate types.

You don't have a format specifier for an array, a structure etc. You have to take individual elements/ members and print them according to their type. You need to understand what is the data (type) that you want to print, and use the appropriate format specifier.

In your case, you can print the member `V`, which is of type `int`. So you can do something like

```
 printf("%d", graph->V);
```

or, if you want to print the pointer returned by `malloc()` and stored into `graph`, you can do

```
  printf("%p", (void *)graph);
```

Finally, [see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right, `graph` has another type than `unsigned int` which would be printed by `%u`. You probably want `graph->V` since there is no other numerical member of the `struct`.

```
printf("%u", graph->V);
```

Also note your `V` has `int` type while you try to print an `unsigned int`.

#### UPDATE

> What format specifier should I use for type `struct Graph *`?

For a pointer, you need the format specifier `%p` and a cast to the type that it accepts.

```
printf("%p", (void*)graph);
```

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/pMOnjO).

Comment: `If you want to print the address of the pointer, you need to cast it to an (unsigned) int.` --> my downvote. Check the documentation.

Comment: Why would you cast a pointer to `unsigned int`? On many platforms pointers are much larger than `unsigned int`. What would be the point of such cast? What would be the meaning of its result?

Comment: @AnT Isn’t `int` the size of the native word of the platform which equals the size of a pointer?

Comment: @Melebius nope, nopes. The cast is required.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What about the [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)?

Comment: @Melebius for a varidic function? Pointer type?

Comment: @Melebius: Not necessarily (albeit indeed that was the intent). You want an integer type of the same width as a pointer - that would be `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`. `unsigned int` on most real-life platforms is pinned at 32-bit width, while pointers can easily have 64.

Comment: `p` is defined for `void`-pointer only. So the code to print its value should be: `printf("%p", (void*) graph);`

Answer (score 0):

See what you will do my friend. Seems you want to print out the value you have assigned to the `int v`.

You are getting that errors because Variable `v` has a return type `int` of which you have not included it your **printf**... Hence

`printf("%u", graph -> v);`